# Drawing a square manually using coordinates

Tags: qgis, polygon, point-in-polygon

I've load points coordinates from a .csv file on QGIS. These points are the intersection of a regular grid.  I would like to select manually four point of this .csv file to draw a square polygon. Also, I would like to measure the length of the edges.

I need this square because the next step is to calculate an intersection with an irregular polygon.

Comment: Toggle snapping, then digitize the rectangle on a new polygon layer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new with QGIS. How I can snapping?

Comment: Before answering your queries here, members expect you to do some research and show what you have already tried. And by research, it means using Google search amongst other things. Members won't teach you everything there is about GIS in general or QGIS or any other software. Looking up some videos on YouTube that explain what snapping is would be a good starting point. And welcome to  GIS SE.

Comment: Can you show a part of this CSV, maybe it's possible to do the squares programmatically instead of manually.